# Including two header files in c++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, header, include

I have a project I'm working on and I'm currently working on the header files. For simplicity let's say I have two header files so far.
fileX.h and fileY.h

The code I have in both is just class definitions. But, fileX needs fileY's class definitions and fileY needs fileX. I tried having inside of fileX a `#include "fileY.h"` and have a `include "fileX.h"` inside of my fileY, but I'm getting an error that gets in a never ending loop. How can I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: The search keyword you're looking for is "circular dependency"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: You cannot have `class A` have `class B` as a member and then `class B` to have `class A` as a member at the same time. You can have a (smart)pointer though. For using pointer you do not need to fully define class. you just use forward declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this ?

By breaking the circular dependency. Its simply impossible for A to depends on B's definition while also B depending on A's definition. You must get rid of one of the dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the circular dependency? Like including everthing in the same file?

Comment: @AhmadSafa Change your program in such way that one doesn't depend on the other.